# Is this class violating Single Responsibility

Tags: oop, single-responsibility-principle

The functionality I wanted to implement is to retrieve some data from database and create a text file out of the data based on some parameters. I created a FileProcessor class which does this.

```
public class FileGenerator
{
public FileGenerator(IDataProvider dataProvider)
{
  // some constructor logic 
}
public void Generate(string fileType)
{
  var data = dataProvider.getData()
  Logger.LogMessage("Retrieved data");
  var file = FileFactory.GetFileInstance(fileType).CreateFile()
  Logger.LogMessage("File Created");
}
}
```

In the above code snippet, constructor takes in dataProvider from the client.
A FileFactory creates an instance of type of file and Create method within the instance actually generates a file. Logger component handles all the logging mechanism and is configurable whether to write to disk or database etc.

Is this class FileGenerator violating SRP?

Comment: Why do you think it is violating and how? Make your point, otherwise question seems too broad.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin - Apart from Generating file, fetching data and logging messages. Can those be considered as additional responsibilities? Is this class dependent on too many other classes?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would disengage the DataProvider entirely from the FileGenerator by using generate(String fileType, Data data) where the data is a separate placeholder class so you can add nice functions to it if you choose to, like toLowerCase() or toString() or whatever you can think of really.

Instead you'd have a managing class that calls the DataProvider, gets the data, puts it in a class they both can use, then pass it into the FileGenerator. The FileGenerator should not know about the DataProvider if it doesn't absolutely have to. Say you make a DifferentDataProvider. How will you reuse FileGenerator. You can't. You'd have to write DifferentFileGenerator so it can call specific methods on your new dataprovider of which FileGenerator has no idea because it gets a DataProvider. It's not a flexible and maintainable design.

As for the logging, that too could be handled by a manager that logs events on succesful method returns. That way, when you swap out your FileGenerator for a different type of FileGenerator you won't have to rewrite all your logging messages.

I'd also use an enum for the fileTypes your filegenerator can generate. It's a lot easier to maintain and a lot clearer which files can be generated.

I hope this helps, be sure to ask for clarification if it doesn't. I strongly recommend reading Head First Design Patterns for standard solutions to many common programming problems.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I like the approach of passing Data directly to the FileGenerator class, since FileGenerator needs data and not how the data is provided to it. On the note of DifferentDataProvider if it can be implementation of IDataProvider, I think it should be fine. Regarding Filetypes I am having it as enum, for the sample I didn't mention all those details here.